# HTTPS Get call with certificate in Rest Assured-> unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: certificate, rest-assured

I need to make HTTPS Get call with certificate in Rest Assured. I had .pfx certificate, I changed it to .jks format. And my code is:

```
  Response resp=given().trustStore("C:\\Users\\userName\\clientcert.jks","Password").
            param("reportId", "111").
            param("startDate","2020-01-01").
            param("endDate", " 2020-01-01").
            when().get(path);
    resp.prettyPrint();
```

When I run this code, it gives me this error: "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
Could you please help me how can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to invoke the below line right before making a request. Like this:

```
RestAssured.config = RestAssured.newConfig().sslConfig(new SSLConfig("C:\\Users\\userName\\clientcert.jks","Password");

  Response resp = given().
            param("reportId", "111").
            param("startDate","2020-01-01").
            param("endDate", " 2020-01-01").
            when().get(path);
  resp.prettyPrint();
```